# Получить данные вошедшего пользователя из firebase JavaScript

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, firebase

Есть веб-приложение, состоящее из нескольких html- страниц. Необходимо выводить на эти страницы информацию из бд firebase о текущем пользователе с помощью JavaScript. При авторизации идет проверка с firebase. Если пользователь там есть, то переход на главную страницу. Оттуда же можно и выйти. Но, если с главной страницы перейти на любую другую, функция выхода не работает и данные о вошедшем пользователе получить нельзя. 
Как получить данные вошедшего пользователя (например, его id в firebase) и передать их на все страницы приложения, чтобы они сохранялись там до полного выхода через кнопку?

Comment: Нужно написать функцию которая будет получать их по api firebase

Comment: Как это сделать? Есть конкретный пример?

Comment: К сожалению точно непомню, посмотрите официальную документацию